# Magento 2 - Load a Form Based on a Shipping Method

Tags: magento2, checkout, email, shipping-methods, forms

I have a shipping extension that has a small form appear when the user selects the shipping method.  The problem is that we used jQuery to show/hide the form based on the selection but the form is always there.  Because it is always there it shows (labels with no data) on the order in the admin and the order emails.  Is there something you know of that will not load the form unless the method is chosen?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: What code do you want me to share?  The jQuery code?